# Best way to group Emails with IMAP? In the same MailBox I need to relate emails to a Project ID

Tags: mailkit, mime-message

In the same MailBox I need to relate emails to a Project ID. 
I can have more that 5000 projects, and each project would have an average of 6 emails.

Later I would like to obtain the emails from the project. How to achieve this?

### headers

I could use Headers, but It would be costly in performance ?!

Since `MimeMessage` `MessageID` may not be unique, should I store my `projectId` here?
Then to get all the project Emails I could use:

```cs
var uids = folder.Search (SearchQuery.HeaderContains ("Message-Id", projectID));
```

### Folders

Folders it would not work? Can I have 5000 folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an `X-Project-Id` header to your messages and then you can search for them like this:

```
folder.Search (SearchQuery.HeaderContains ("X-Project-Id", "myprojectid"));
```